# Rails model can't access belongs_to model even though foreign key exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Model called Challenge that is created by a User. It has a Difficulty associated with it as well. When I create the Challenge and hand it the Author (User) and Difficulty, the Difficulty associate works, but the Author (User) one doesn't. The weirdest part is, when you look at the Challenge object, it shows the Author key its associated with.

```
challenge = Challenge.first
challenge.author (prints Nil) #Doesn't even run a Query
```

When I create a Challenge using the following code, the user_id is Nil.

```
user = User.find(1)
diff = Difficulty.find(1)
Challenge.create(:author => user, :difficulty => diff, :title => "My Challenge")
```

When I create a Challenge using this code, the User gets the relation to the Challenge and the Challenge gets the user_id of the User. But you can only go from User to Challenge. Challenge to User returns Nil.

```
user = User.find(1)
diff = Difficulty.find(1)
chall = Challenge.create(:difficulty => diff, :title => "My Challenge")
user.authored_challenges << chall
```

Here are my Models and Tables

```
# Models
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authored_challenges, :class_name => "Challenge"
  attr_accessible :display_name, :authored_challenges   
end

class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :challenges
  attr_accessible :name, :value, :challenges
end

class Challenge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reward
  belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :reward, :author
end

# Tables
create_table :users do |t|
  t.string :display_name
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :rewards do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.float :value
  t.timestamps
end

create_table :challenges do |t|
  t.integer :user_id
  t.integer :reward_id
  t.string :title
  t.string :description
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: I should add. If I change the model names from Author to User. It works just fine. So the rename is the issue. Something must have changed in Rails 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html the foreign key should be:

```
:foreign_key => :author_id
```

Don't forget to add the field.  Good Luck!

Comment: I don't know why this worked, and using :foreign_key => :user_id didn't. But once I did this and changed the table to use author_id, it all came together. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => :user_id
```

From the Rails documentation:

> By convention, Rails assumes that the column used to hold the foreign key on this model is the name of the association with the suffix _id added. The :foreign_key option lets you set the name of the foreign key directly

The example given in the docs is very similar to the one you have:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => "Patron", :foreign_key => "patron_id"
end
```

Comment: I should note, this actually did work as well. I had to add the foreign_key to both the belongs_to and the has_many

Comment: So adding the foreign_key to both sides was key. Cool.